# How to use 'fout' with inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, ofstream

I'm taking a class in C++ and I've run into a problem. We have to create a list of bankaccounts that each have their own savings and checking account. I've come quite far, but now I have to use "ofstream& fout" to print the checking and savings of an imaginairy account.

My header file of "Account.h" looks like this (I think it's correct):

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#ifndef ACCOUNT_H
#define ACCOUNT_H

using namespace std;

class Account{
protected:
    string number;
    double balance;    
public:
    Account(){}
    Account(string nr, double bl);
    void deposit(double am);
    string get_number();
    double get_balance();
    double withdraw(double am);
    bool equals(Account other);
    virtual void print();
    void println();
    void println(string s);
    virtual void println(ofstream& fout);
    virtual void read(ifstream& fin);
};

#endif
```

My definition file is where it all goes horribly wrong with the fstream part:

```
#include "Account.h"

Account::Account(string nr, double bl){
    if (bl >= 0){
        number = nr;
        balance = bl;
    }
    else{
        number = "incorrect";
    }    
}

void Account::deposit(double am){
    if (am >= 0){
        balance = balance + am;
    }
}

string Account::get_number(){ 
    return number;
}

double Account::get_balance(){
    return balance;
}

double Account::withdraw(double am){
    if (0 <= am && am <= get_balance()){
        balance = balance - am;
        return am;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}

bool Account::equals(Account other){
    if (number == other.get_number()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void Account::print(){
    cout << "<Account(" << number << ",";
    cout << balance << ")>" ;
}

void Account::println(){
    print();
    cout << endl;
}

void Account::println(string s){
    cout << s;
    println();
}

void Account::println(ofstream& fout){
    fout << number << ",";
    fout << balance;
    fout << endl;
}

void Account::read(ifstream& fin){
    fin >> number;
}
```

There is something wrong with the declaration of void Account::println(ofstream& fout). It gives me the output

```
<Account(number,balance,0)>
```

instead of

```
<Account(number,balance)>
```

Why does this happen? I have many more problems with the printing of the savings and checking numbers, but i feel if I understand why this is happening I can solve those. Thank you to anyone who wants to help me.

Answer (score 0):

`Account::println(ofstream&)` will print "", but since the balance is a double, it prints with a decimal place:

if balance == 0.0, it will be printed as eiter 0.0 or 0,0, depending on your locale.

Either way, you have way too many print methods, and I think the solution should be implemented through an output operator:

Header:

```
class Account {
    // ....
    // no print methods defined
};
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Account& a);
```

Source:
    std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const Account& a)
    {
        return out << "";
    }

Client code:

```
#include <iostream> // console
#include <fstream>  // file

Account a;
// print to console
std::cout << a << std::endl;
// print to file
std::ofstream fout("./account.txt");
fout << a << std::endl;
```

Comment: I know I have too many print methods, but that is all in the assignment. I have to do it this way and with the normal println(), the balance is also a double. The ",0" does not appear there though.

I know there is a way to do it like this with fstream, I just don't know how.

Comment: Consider printing `static_cast<int>(balance)` instead (or better yet, use `std::setprecision(3)` or similar, on both). It is possible that std::cout and std::ofstream instance use different formatting flags by default.